# Error inputing data into the database using Room, Dao

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

This is my first time using Room and LiveData. I keep getting errors about inputing data into the database using Dao(Database access object). I have tried updating build.gradle files, but it doesn't solve the errors. It says "getDatabase called recursively".

My logcat below:

```
 2019-08-01 13:35:55.644 18117-18149/com.example.inventory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
    Process: com.example.inventory, PID: 18117
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:338)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:452)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:275)
        at com.example.inventory.data.InventoryDao_Impl.insert(InventoryDao_Impl.java:58)
        at com.example.inventory.data.InventoryRoomDatabase$PopulateDbAsync.<init>(InventoryRoomDatabase.java:46)
        at com.example.inventory.data.InventoryRoomDatabase$1.onOpen(InventoryRoomDatabase.java:34)
        at com.example.inventory.data.InventoryRoomDatabase_Impl$1.onOpen(InventoryRoomDatabase_Impl.java:58)
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:120)
```

Room database class

```
@Database(entities = Product.class, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class InventoryRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract InventoryDao inventoryDao();

    public static InventoryRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static InventoryRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        synchronized (InventoryRoomDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        InventoryRoomDatabase.class, "inventory_table")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().addCallback(roomDatabaseCallback).build();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();

        }
    };

    private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final InventoryDao mDao;
        Product product = new Product("Ice cream", 0.99, 70);

        PopulateDbAsync(InventoryRoomDatabase db) {
            mDao = db.inventoryDao();
            mDao.insert(product);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Dao interface

```
@Dao
public interface InventoryDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Product product);

    @Query("DELETE FROM inventory_table")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * from inventory_table")
    LiveData<List<Product>> getAllProducts();
}
```

Comment: where are you calling getDatabase()?

Answer (score 4):

your db data insertion process is working on main thread and there are no permission to access room db on main thread, to access db on main thread try below code.

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(AppInjector.getApplication(), AppDb.class, DbConstant.DATABASENAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the entity had changed and when I compiled it was giving a database that was not comparable with the entity I was trying to make and that is why it gave me that error after I uninstalled the application it stopped giving that error